# Add a scrollbar to a modal box in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

im created a modal box using prototype.js using the following code, i want to add the scroll to this , how can i add that ?

```
Modalbox.show($('viewModalbox-'+questionid),{
    title: question,
    width: 500,
    overlayClose: false,
    overlayOpacity: 0.25
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [ModalBox site](http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/):

> ***NEW!* “Scrolling mode”.** If your content might be long just define the height of the ModalBox and it will be switched into “scrolling mode”

So you just need to add a height value!

```
Modalbox.show($('viewModalbox-'+questionid),{
    title: question,
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    overlayClose: false,
    overlayOpacity: 0.25
});
```